# I'm trying to append a Rig that is split up into collections, but whenever I append it, it breaks

Tags: mesh, rigging, append

Regular Rig
[image: Regular Rig]

Regular Scene Collection
[image: Regular Scene Collection]

Appended Rig
[image: Appended Rig]

Appended Scene Collection
[image: RAppended Scene Collection]